# starting application always with new task in android

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which first of all user login in the second activity and moves to third activity.

If user directly quits from second page i have used movetasktoback(true) so application closes from third activity.

If user again open application then third activity is shown directly for this in main(first) activity i have stored user information in preferences which decide that either to go on second activity or login screen or to third activity.

if user want to close application i have a diff activity which logout the application and moves to second activity.if user closes application from login screen i have used movetasttoback true which easily closes the app.

Everything is fine till now. but if user again start application after 1 hr to login as user login the screen it opens fifth or sixth activity which was last opened and application behave in bugging way.

Please tell how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so do one thing when you close your application actually it runs on background.

After opening the application you lancing a new task for that put on appropriate class's:

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {      
           Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(setIntent);
        ClaasName.this.finish();
```

I hope that will helps you.

Comment: don't use system.exit(0) ever i have read this on stackoverflow.